# vector sort - c++

Tags: c++

I have a vector that that stores Node*. A Node has the member properties:row,col,value. In my vector, I have gotten it to where all the Nodes* within the same row but not necessarily in correct column order. So basically I want to sort it so it's truly in row-major form. Right now, the columns are out of order within each "row". I appreciate any help you could give!

Edit:

Here is the method I have that is sorting my vector by row. Is there a way to additionally sort the columns as well?

```
    vector<Node*> vect;
    int i,j,minIndex;
    Node* temp = new Node(NULL,NULL,0,0,0);
    for(i=0;i<vect.size()-1;i++)
    {
        minIndex = i;
        for(j=i+1;j<vect.size();j++)
        {
            if(vect.at(j)->row<vect.at(minIndex)->row)
            {
                minIndex = j;
            }
        }
        if(minIndex!=i)
        {
            temp = vect.at(i);
            vect.at(i) = vect.at(minIndex);
            vect.at(minIndex) = temp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code you have so far.

Comment: Incidentally, what you are asking about is known as a [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Comment: I have run into another problem. I now want to add two matrices together. So the issue is when i combine all the nodes of both matrices into a common vector, there might be multiple nodes with the same row and col, one from each matrix. I want to add their "value" fields together so that it is represented as one single Node in the new matrix. I appreciate any help or a way to start this problem. I have been thinking for the last hour and have drawn a blank.

Comment: I think you should go ahead and ask this as a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to implement your own sorting algorithm here.  You can just use the standard template library's sort() method and then override default the behavior for sorting your Node* vector.

```
// This returns true if Node* a should be considered "less than" Node* b.
    struct less_node : binary_function <Node*,Node*,bool> 
    {
        bool operator() (const Node*& a, const Node*& b) const
        {
                // sort by row first
            if (a->row < b->row)  
                return true;
                // then sort by col within each row
            if (a->row == b->row && a->col < b->col)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Once you have this less_node structure defined, you would just call:

```
sort(vect.begin(), vect.end(), less_node());
```

Comment: I am familiar with iterators and such, but I am slightly confused with defining the operator() within the less_node struct. I am getting an error in eclipse. It says "Multiple markers at this line
 - expected template-name before ‘<’ 
  token
 - expected ‘{’ before ‘<’ token
 - expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ 
  token"

Comment: Did you remember to declare the `Node` class above the `struct less_node`?

Comment: Also, you will need to #include <vector>, <functional> and <algorithm>

Comment: I have run into another problem. I now want to add two matrices together. So the issue is when i combine all the nodes of both matrices into a common vector, there might be multiple nodes with the same row and col, one from each matrix. I want to add their "value" fields together so that it is represented as one single Node in the new matrix. I appreciate any help or a way to start this problem. I have been thinking for the last hour and have drawn a blank.